# Equality involving Appell hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, power-series, indefinite-integrals

After some algebra, *Wolfram online integrator* gave me the following:
$$\tag{1} \int (1-a-t)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{2t-t^2}\ \text{d} t = c\ \cdot t^{3/2}\ \operatorname{F}_1 \left( \frac{3}{2}; -\frac{1}{2}, 2-N; \frac{5}{2}; \frac{t}{2}, \frac{t}{1-a}\right)+C$$
where:

- $\operatorname{F}_1$ is the [*Appell hypergeometric function of two variables*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html) defined by the expansion:
  $$\operatorname{F}_1(\alpha; \beta, \beta^\prime ; \gamma; x,y):= \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha)_{m+n}\ (\beta)_m\ (\beta^\prime)_n}{m!\ n!\ (\gamma)_{m+n}}\ x^m\ y^n$$
  ($(a_k):=\frac{\Gamma (a+k)}{\Gamma(a)}$ is the [*Pochhammer symbol*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)), which converges in the region $|x|,|y|<1$;
- $N\geq 3$ an integer, $a\in ]0,1[$ and $t\in [0,1-a]$ (so the RHside makes sense);
- $c=c(a,N)$ is a known constant and $C$ is an arbitrary constant (coming from indefinite integration).

My question is:

> How can I get (**1**) without using any software?

I suppose a series expansion of the integrand and term by term integration should be used, but I could not figure out how to do explicit computations.
Neither I succeeded in simplifying the derivative of the LHside to get the integrand...

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found also the following term-by-term integration solution.

One has:
$$(1-a-t)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{2t-t^2} = \sqrt{2}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{t}\ \left( 1-\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{1-\frac{t}{2}}$$
and by the *binomial theorem*:
$$\begin{split}
\left( 1-\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^{N-2} &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-2} (-1)^k\ \binom{N-2}{k}\ \left(\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-2} \frac{(2-N)_k}{k!}\ \left(\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2-N)_k}{k!}\ \left(\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^k\\
\sqrt{1-\frac{t}{2}} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\ \binom{1/2}{k}\ \left( \frac{t}{2}\right)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/2)_k}{k!}\ \left( \frac{t}{2}\right)^k\; ;
\end{split}$$
now, since both series in the rightmost sides converge absolutely, *Mertens theorem* applies and one can take the Cauchy product:
$$\begin{split} \left( 1-\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{1-\frac{t}{2}} &= \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2-N)_k}{k!}\ \left(\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^k\right)*\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/2)_k}{k!}\ \left( \frac{t}{2}\right)^k\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{h=0}^k \frac{(2-N)_h}{h!}\ \left(\frac{t}{1-a}\right)^h\ \frac{(-1/2)_{k-h}}{(k-h)!}\ \left( \frac{t}{2}\right)^{k-h}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{h=0}^k \frac{(2-N)_h\ (-1/2)_{k-h}}{h!\ (k-h)!}\ \frac{1}{2^h\ (1-a)^{k-h}}\ t^k
\end{split}$$
with the rigthmost side converging absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets.
Therefore one gets:
$$(1-a-t)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{2t-t^2} = \sqrt{2}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{h=0}^k \frac{(2-N)_h\ (-1/2)_{k-h}}{h!\ (k-h)!}\ \frac{1}{2^h\ (1-a)^{k-h}}\ t^{k+1/2}$$
and a rearrangement of the RHside yields:
$$(1-a-t)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{2t-t^2} = \sqrt{2}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{(2-N)_m\ (-1/2)_n}{m!\ n!}\ \frac{1}{2^m\ (1-a)^n}\ t^{m+n+1/2}\; ;$$
thus term-by-term integration shows that:
$$\begin{split}
\int (1-a-t)^{N-2}\ \sqrt{2t-t^2}\ \text{d} t &= \sqrt{2}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{(2-N)_m\ (-1/2)_n}{m!\ n!}\ \frac{1}{2^m\ (1-a)^n}\ \int t^{m+n+1/2}\ \text{d} t\\
&= \sqrt{2}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{(2-N)_m\ (-1/2)_n}{m!\ n!\ (3/2 +m+n)}\ \frac{1}{2^m\ (1-a)^n}\ t^{m+n+3/2}\ + C\\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{(3/2)_{m+n}\ (2-N)_m\ (-1/2)_n}{m!\ n!\ (5/2)_{m+n}}\ \frac{1}{2^m\ (1-a)^n}\ t^{m+n+3/2}\\
&\phantom{=} +C\\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\ (1-a)^{N-2}\ t^{3/2}\ F_1\left( \frac{3}{2}; -\frac{1}{2}, 2-N; \frac{5}{2}; \frac{t}{2}, \frac{t}{1-a}\right) +C
\end{split}$$
because:
$$\frac{3}{2}\ \frac{1}{m+n+3/2} = \frac{(3/2)_{m+n}}{(5/2)_{m+n}}\; .$$

Answer (score 3):

It is an application of following [integral formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/07/01/01/) for $\operatorname{F}_1$ :
$$\operatorname{F}_1(a;b_1,b_2;c;z_1,z_2)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{c-a-1}(1-x z_1)^{-b_1}(1-x z_2)^{-b_2}\,dx$$

giving :
$$\operatorname{F}_1 \left( \frac 32; -\frac 12, 2-N; \frac 52; \frac t2, \frac t{1-a}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac 52)}{\Gamma(\frac 32)}\int_0^1 x^{\frac 12}\left(1-x \frac t2\right)^{\frac 12}\left(1-x \frac t{1-a}\right)^{N-2}\, dx$$

$$=\frac 32 t^{-\frac 12-1}\int_0^t y^{\frac 12}\left(1-\frac y2\right)^{\frac 12}\left(1-\frac y{1-a}\right)^{N-2}\, dy$$

$$=t^{-\frac 32} C_1\int_0^t \sqrt{2y-y^2}\left(1-a-y\right)^{N-2}\, dy$$

i.e. your result (with $\frac 1c=C_1$ 'absorbing' the constants involved).

Hoping this helped,

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond... As you can see below I found also a different solution.

Comment: @Pacciu: Fine! So that you'll have a proof from integrals and sums point of view!